# Rendering backbone views with collection in callbacks

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

Here is a view I am working with:

```
class Raffler.Views.EntriesIndex extends Backbone.View
  template: JST['entries/index']

  initialize: ->
    @collection.on('reset', @render, this)

  render: ->
    Raffler.entries = @collection
    $(@el).html(@template(eventSource: (start, end, callback) ->
      console.log @collection # = undefined
      callback(Raffler.entries.events(start, end))
    ))
```

I had to assign window.Raffler property to my collection to be able to use it in the callback. Is there a nice way of using something like `callback(@collection.events(start, end))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In coffeescript, if you use the "fat arrow" (`=>`) operator instead of `->`, your callback function will be bound to the `this` (`@`) in the scope in which it is created. This means you can use @collection within your callback and @ will properly refer to your EntriesIndex, so your render function can just look like this:

```
render: ->
  $(@el).html(@template(eventSource: (start, end, callback) =>
    console.log @collection # == your EntriesIndex collection
    callback(@collection.events(start, end))
  ))
```

See http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow

My suggestion above will only work if `this` (`@`) refers to your EntriesIndex within render, so I believe you may have to do as Abraham suggested as well and make sure to bind @ to your EntriesIndex within the render function. Add this to initialize:

```
_.bindAll this
```

Someone who knows Coffeescript can correct me if I'm wrong on that syntax :)

Answer (score 1):

Inside of `initialize` if you `this.bindAll(this);` then `this.collection` should work inside of `render`.